# I am stuck trying to create from a Blazor wasm template with Swagger. I can see swagger before publish but not after

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am using dotnet 7 to create a template wasm.  I have added Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to the server project.  I have added to the server Project Program.cs ... I publish from the Client project.  I am stuck please advise.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// Add Swagger.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

// Use Swagger.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't create a global.json file // opened in private browser.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).